# AJAX applying too big array to $scope variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs

I'm getting an array of JSON objects with an AJAX call. Which I then apply to a $scope variable in Angular. So far so good, but when the result gets larger (around 17kb or more), it will fail.

How exactly does it fail? The window in my browser will freeze. I can't click any links or scroll in that specific tab in my browser (Google Chrome). When I look at the network tab in Chrome's developers console, the preview/response of the AJAX call is just white... nothing. But when I copy paste the request URL in my browser, I just get the data I expect to get and it also works for the bigger sized data without problems.

Commenting out every line of code I have found that the following line will make it crash:

```
$scope.reservaties = data.reservaties;
```

A wider view on the surrounding code:

```
// … stome ajax stuff

if (data.reservaties) {
      console.log(data.reservaties); 
      $scope.$apply(function () {
           $scope.reservaties = data.reservaties; // if put in comment, everything else will work as expected
      });
}

// …
```

A simplified example of the data object:

```
{“reservaties”:[{“id”:”1”,”name”:”foo”},{“id”:”1”,”name”:”bar”}]}
```

Not that it matters but the server side runs on PHP 5.1.6 (I know it's ancient, but I can't update it as it is a school server).

**Edit:  I just noticed a small difference in the responsive headers. The one that fails has a response header: "Transfer-Encoding:chunked"** Might be relevant?

Comment: Have you tried making the ajax call async? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Does it unfreeze after a time or does it remain frozen? Also, please post the code that makes the AJAX call.

Comment: 17kb is not big at all actually - i think u use that big array in wrong way. What are u doing with this data later on?

Comment: Have a read at this it's interesting http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/648526/All-about-http-chunked-responses

Comment: @Petr 17kb isn't big indeed, it are around 15 items of dummy data. It can easily get over a 1000 items. I thought a MB or 2 would be ok. What am I doing with the data? I add it to a $scope variable in angular to render it as a table with pagination and all that and also in a graph. It's a list of reservations including every data about them but I don't think that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the async property of the [ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). My guess is that your call is made synchronously, which is causing the window to freeze until the ajax action is complete.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  async: true
}).done(function() {
 // do stuff
});
```

Comment: That did not work. I just noticed a small difference in the responsive headers. The one that fails has a response header: "Transfer-Encoding:chunked"

Comment: Oh alright. Interesting, wouldn't have thought of that. Thanks for the update!